# web2py ajax login wrong password redirects to wrong page

Tags: authentication, web2py

I'd like to create web page with ajax login form. That's what I have:

controller:

```
def login_form():
    loginForm = auth.login()
    return loginForm
```

view:

```
        <div class="loginFormLayout">
            {{=LOAD('default', 'login_form', ajax=True)}}
        </div>
```

and here is my auth.settings:

```
auth.settings.remember_me_form = False
auth.settings.login_next = URL('main')
auth.settings.logout_next = URL('index')
```

Now if I login, page is redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/default/main` (as should be). If I write wrong e-mail, error message is shown. But if I write proper e-mail and wrong password, page is redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/default/login_form`. I'd like to stop redirect after wrong password submission.

I've tied  with

```
auth.settings.on_failed_authentication = lambda url: redirect(URL('index'))
auth.settings.on_failed_authorization =     URL('index',args='on_failed_authorization')
```

it doesn't help.

Also turning off user scripts is not good solution, because it prevents from redirect after proper login.

How to properly provide error message for wrong password without redirection and page reload?